# What can cause NSXML Parser to Crash?

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, nsxmlparser

I have an xml file that reads something like

```
<html>
  <head style="">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body style="">current=yes<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?-->
    <results>
      ... (Some tags and content)
    </results>  
  </body>
</html>
```

My `didStartElement` method is not getting called at all. Is it crashing due to the text after the `body` tag? If so, is there any way to change the file in the app before the `NSXMLParser` gets to it?

The parser is initialized here:

```
NSURL *url       = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data     = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser           = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate  = self;
[parser parse];
```

and

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"Element: %@", elementName);
    ...
}
```

No element names are outputted.

Comment: Show us how you're creating and using it. Check that the parser initializes correctly.

Comment: @Kevin Added the parser initialization.

Comment: What makes you think it's crashing? If it crashes. It will bring your whole app down. Have you implemented any of the other delegate methods?

Comment: Check that parser is not null after you initialize it. If it has a problem reading the file it'll probably return null from the init.

Comment: @jrturton Maybe crashing is not the right word. What I know is that when the parser is called, the output "Element: %@" is not being executed at all. I have implemented `foundCharacters` and `didEndElement`.

Comment: @Kevin I added `NSLog(@"Parser: %@", parser)` right after `[parser parse]` and it returned `Parser: <NSXMLParser: 0x8be88a0>`. So not null.

Comment: Is it a problem that your first `body` element is not closed?  I've never seen `<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?-->` in the middle of the file, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that there was text that came before the

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?-->
```

tag.

On another note, the preceding tags (`html`, `head`, and `body`) turn out to not be part of the file, but added by the browser in order to display the file. A precise output of what is being parsed can be created by converting the `NSData` into a `NSString` variable and logging it:

```
NSURL *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data      = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"XMLData: %@", strData);
```

This outputted something like

```
current=yes<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?-->
<results>
  ... (Some tags and content)
</results>
```

and from this output it is easy to see that there is initial text causing an error.